# How to make this sum? Client Server UDP

Tags: java

i have a client that send to a server two integers: the server have to sum them and send again the result to the client. I don't understand how can i do this sum because i don't have two integers but:

```
public class UDPServer {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception { 

DatagramSocket serverSocket= new DatagramSocket(1200);



byte[] receiveDataA = new byte[4];
byte[] receiveDataB = new byte[4]; 
byte[] sendDataSum = new byte[4];//  = new byte[1024]; 


while(true) { 

    DatagramPacket receivePacketA = new DatagramPacket(receiveDataA, receiveDataA.length); 
    serverSocket.receive(receivePacketA); 

    DatagramPacket receivePacketB = new DatagramPacket(receiveDataA, receiveDataA.length); 
    serverSocket.receive(receivePacketB);

    String a = new String(receivePacketA.getData(), 0, receivePacketA.getLength()); 
    String b = new String(receivePacketB.getData(), 0, receivePacketB.getLength()); 

    /*here i have to make the sum..how?
    */


    InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacketA.getAddress(); 

    int port = receivePacketA.getPort(); 
    DatagramPacket sendPacketSum = new  DatagramPacket(sendDataSum, sendDataSum.length, IPAddress, port); 

    serverSocket.send(sendPacketSum); 




} 

}
```

}

Comment: Assuming the code getting `a` and `b` works, you might want to look at [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

Comment: The actual question has nothing to do with UDP. It appears to be about the mysterious + operator.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Integer.parseInt(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) method

so:

```
int aVal = Integer.parseInt(a);
int bVal = Integer.parseInt(b);
int sum = aVal + bVal
```

Then you can use something like [ByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) to get your byte array

```
sendDataSum = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(sum).array();
```